# Health Checks UI (BeatPulse) not able to get Teams webhook working

Tags: asp.net-core, webhooks, health-monitoring

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 app that is using health checks and health checks UI. I have that portion working, but when I try to add a webhook for Teams it is not showing up.

I followed the example in the [documentation](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/master/doc/webhooks.md#microsoft-teams):

> ```
> "Webhooks": [
>       {
>         "Name": "Teams",
>         "Uri": "https://outlook.office.com/webhook/...",
>         "Payload": "{\r\n  \"@context\": \"http://schema.org/extensions\",\r\n  \"@type\": \"MessageCard\",\r\n \"themeColor\": \"0072C6\",\r\n  \"title\": \"[[LIVENESS]] has failed!\",\r\n  \"text\": \"[[FAILURE]] Click **Learn More** to go to BeatPulseUI Portal\",\r\n  \"potentialAction\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"@type\": \"OpenUri\",\r\n      \"name\": \"Lear More\",\r\n      \"targets\": [\r\n        { \"os\": \"default\", \"uri\": \"http://localhost:52665/beatpulse-ui\" }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}",
>         "RestoredPayload": "{\"text\":\"The HealthCheck [[LIVENESS]] is recovered. All is up and running\",\"channel\":\"#general\",\"link_names\": 1,\"username\":\"monkey-bot\",\"icon_emoji\":\":monkey_face"
>       }
>     ],
> ```

I tried [calling the webhook directly with cURL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors-using#post-a-message-to-the-webhook-using-curl) and this works as expected:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"text\": \"Hello World\"}" <YOUR WEBHOOK URL>
```

I also tried simplifying the `Payload`:

```
"Webhooks": [
    {
      "Name": "Teams",
      "Uri": "https://outlook.office.com/webhook/...",
      "Payload": "{\"text\":\"[[LIVENESS]] has failed! Failure: [[FAILURE]]\" }",
      "RestoredPayload": "{\"text\": \"The HealthCheck [[LIVENESS]] has recovered. \" }"
    }
]
```

Still no joy. When I start up the page I see no webhooks displayed, but I do see this error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at new e.HttpResponse (healthchecks-bundle.js:formatted:473)
    at XMLHttpRequest.l.onload (healthchecks-bundle.js:formatted:505)
```

Which is referring to this:

```
e.HttpResponse = class {
    constructor(A) {
        const {status: e, statusText: t, response: a, responseText: n} = A;
        this.status = e,
        this.statusText = t,
        this.response = a || n,
        this.data = JSON.parse(this.response) // line 473
    }
}
```

Looking at the network tab I see a call to `“healthchecks-webhooks”`. The response from this looks like html, but when I go directly to the page it is a json response with the Teams webhook.

Here’s how I’m setting up healthchecks:

```
.UseHealthChecks("/health", new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckOptions()
 {
     Predicate = _ => true,
     ResponseWriter = HealthChecks.UI.Client.UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
 })
 .UseHealthChecksUI()
```

Is there some other configuration I’m missing? How can I get the Teams webhook to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebHooks.RestoredPayload json doesn't have a closing quote and brace which is causing the parse error.

try this json insetad:

```
"Webhooks": [
      {
        "Name": "Teams",
        "Uri": "https://outlook.office.com/webhook/...",
        "Payload": "{\r\n  \"@context\": \"http://schema.org/extensions\",\r\n  \"@type\": \"MessageCard\",\r\n \"themeColor\": \"0072C6\",\r\n  \"title\": \"[[LIVENESS]] has failed!\",\r\n  \"text\": \"[[FAILURE]] Click **Learn More** to go to BeatPulseUI Portal\",\r\n  \"potentialAction\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"@type\": \"OpenUri\",\r\n      \"name\": \"Lear More\",\r\n      \"targets\": [\r\n        { \"os\": \"default\", \"uri\": \"http://localhost:52665/beatpulse-ui\" }\r\n      ]\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}",
        "RestoredPayload": "{\"text\":\"The HealthCheck [[LIVENESS]] is recovered. All is up and running\",\"channel\":\"#general\",\"link_names\": 1,\"username\":\"monkey-bot\",\"icon_emoji\":\":monkey_face\" }"
      }
    ],
```